# Understanding $watch in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am a little confused with the `$watch` syntax in AngularJS.

Given a variable `$scope.foo`, with initial value of `[1,2,3]`, and update causes it to now equal `[1,2]`.  I want a function to be run whenever `$scope.foo` is updated, with `$scope.foo` as arg.

How do I do this in AngularJS?

Answer (score 8):

That's pretty simple:

```js
function myFunction(foo) {
    // do something with `foo`
}

$scope.$watch('foo', function(newValue, oldValue) { 
    myFunction(newValue);
});
```

More details are found in the [AngularJS documentation about $watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

Comment: You can add the $ sign before the 'scope'

Comment: @TidharPeer You're right, done that.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to get it to work with `$http`, [here's what I've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16883446).