# $watch not working on variable from other controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have one controller which displays a checklist, and stores the selection in an array.

My other controller runs an `$http.get` on the array from the first controller.

How do I set a `$watch` so that whenever the array changes, a new HTTP GET request is sent?

My attempt: http://plnkr.co/edit/EaCbnKrBQdEe4Nhppdfa

```js
// See plnkr for other controller + FooSelection factory + view
function SimpleQueryResCtrl($scope, $http, FooSelection) {
    $scope.foo_list_selection = FooSelection;

    $scope.$watch('foo_list_selection', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue)
            $http.get('/api/' + $scope.foo_list_selection).success(function (largeLoad) {
                $scope.myData = largeLoad;
            });
    });
}

SimpleQueryResCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'FooSelection'];
```

Comment: I think your code is correct, are you getting errors? You could also check if newValue !== oldValue to make sure your request if fired only when 'foo_list_selection' really changes.

Comment: Okay, I believe this is the simplest runnable example I can make: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2mcTX0NxjifvvqynNfV6). You should see in your console that HTTP requests were made, but none were made from this example.

Comment: I fixed some errors in your plunker, it seems to be working fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/nnRw4Pu5x9YQyyqWPc4h?p=preview

Comment: It is working for me, every time I type something in the input a get request if being fired to /api/ + foo_list_selection.

Comment: Thanks, your sample does work. Unfortunately when I switch from `input` tag to my checkbox tag it fails.

Comment: This plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/3ExrhzF9sD8bucXiNuRv?p=preview is working using a checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately my problem seems to be with sharing an array between controllers. [Here is my version](http://plnkr.co/edit/EaCbnKrBQdEe4Nhppdfa), which doesn't work.

Comment: I have edited the question to properly highlight the problem.

Comment: Adding `true` as the third parameter to `$watch` seems to work (as @sh0ber already suggested).  I used `$timeout` instead of `$http` to simulate server activity: [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oP0xrdMukoFiPsLgkpOx?p=preview).

Answer (score 3):

By default, a `$watch` checks for changes to a reference, not for equality. Since objects and arrays still have the same reference when modified, the watch is not triggered.  There are at least two options to get it working.

If the only changes you want to be notified of modify the size of the array (adding or removing elements vs. changing the content of an element), you can set the watch on the length property of the array instead like:

```
$scope.$watch('foo_list_selection.length', function (newValue, oldValue) {
// ...
```

Otherwise, you can use the optional `$watch` argument `objectEquality`, which expects a boolean. This does an equality check rather than a reference check.

```
$scope.$watch('foo_list_selection', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue)
        $http.get('/api/' + $scope.foo_list_selection).success(function (largeLoad) {
        $scope.myData = largeLoad;
    });
}, true);  // <- put `true` here
```

This is not the default behavior because it performs a more costly deep check of all the elements so only use when necessary.

Comment: Thanks, fairly certain that's the answer I'm looking for. Couldn't get it to work with this example though, perhaps you could help? - I wrapped lines [13-40 of main.js](http://plnkr.co/edit/4LyAek) with that `$scope.$watch` conditional, on a variable that was injected in (and brought into $scope). It didn't work :(. This is from the [ng-grid paging example](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/#/paging) BTW.

Comment: Those lines seem to be function definitions so I'm thinking they are probably not what you really want in the watch body. Maybe you could post your new code (with the watch wrap) and a new question about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Moving some of that logic into the factory, then sending it out to all controllers with a `$rootScope.$broadcast` will get your information to the correct places.

I moved the array creation into the factory, then used the $broadcast from there:

```
myApp.factory('FooSelection', function ($rootScope) {
var tempArr = [];
var fixArray = function(item){
  if (tempArr.indexOf(item) === -1){
    tempArr.push(item);
  } else {
    tempArr.splice(tempArr.lastIndexOf(item), 1);
  }
  $rootScope.$broadcast('newArray', tempArr);

}

return {fixArray: fixArray}
})
```

Using `$scope.$on` in the controllers receives the new data when it changes:

```
function SimpleQueryResCtrl($scope, $http, FooSelection) {
$scope.foo_list_selection = FooSelection;

$scope.$on('newArray', function(evt, message){
  console.log(message) // and you can put your $get method here
})
}
```

[Here's the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/pABrl2yeOyLfOhraqjcY?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, I recommend using a service for data manipulation and messages to keep the controllers and UI in sync.

Take a look here: [AngularJS multiple uses of Controller and rootScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180293/angularjs-multiple-uses-of-controller-and-rootscope/13181133#13181133)