# What is 'cheaper' performance-wise $broadcast or $watch

Tags: angularjs

I have a situation in my application where I need to reload the menu each time the role of the user changes(One user can have roles in several companies).

I was wondering what is the best way to approach this issue.

currently I am doing the following:

```
app.controller('menuLoadingCtrl', function($location, $scope, authService){
    $scope.model.initialRole = authService.getRole();
    $scope.$watch(function(){return authService.getRole()}, function(val){
        if(val && val != $scope.model.initialRole){
                $scope.layout.menuSrc = 'partials/menu.html';
        }
    });
})
```

Simple redirecting the user to the menu loading view, and from there, back to the menu view once the role is done loading.
I have this wrapped in a function:

```
 $scope.layout.reloadMenu = function(){
        $scope.layout.menuSrc = 'partials/menuLoading.html';
    }
```

which I call at any scenario at which I would like to reload the menu.

I was wondering if I can make this process more automatic by broadcasting this event from the service on the $rootScope, and then listening to it in the controller.

Any thoughts\advice on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`$watch()` is doing dirt-checking: the function makes a comparison each digest cycle. On the other hand, `$broadcast()` propagates an event only when there is one. Naturally, `$broadcast()` is cheaper than `$watch()`.

But did you really have to worry about performance here? One primitive comparison by cycle is nothing. However, conceptually, `$watch()` is clearly what you need: you want to do an action **each time a variable changes**. I can't imagine using `$broadcast()` here.

Comment: +1 clear and concise. I'd just like to add that OP's code should not have `$watch` or `$broadcast` in the controller in the first place - rather OP should wrap `authService` in an Angular service or better yet, a `$q` promise.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer.
I guess it is the right path to go then, the only problem is that this way I need to call a certain function each time I want to reload the menu, which causes a larger amount of code, hence more maintenance.
Doing the dirty checking on the service level, and broadcasting an eveny will make this action automatic, however will not allow me to show a loader while the request to the server resolves.

Comment: Also I need to set a flag for the controller for a case in which I set the role type synchronously, such as log-in \ log-out.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain more in details why and where you contemplate to use broadcasting. It's not quite clear right now.

Comment: You are right. [This test convinced me.](http://jsperf.com/angular-broadcast-vs-watch)

Comment: what to think about [these tests](http://jsperf.com/service-angular-broadcast-vs-watch) ?

Comment: @vianney: On top of being visibly slower, the watch test crashes the tab at iteration 9 or 10 for me.

Comment: @Blackhole, $scope.$watch doesn't help when you want to update data from other controller(different scope) like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883446/