# Angular update scope from event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an angular service which manages Authentication to the app. And a controller.

service fires an even on `$rootScope` when the user logs in and logs out.

I want to update the DOM element in my UI, so it shows either 'Login' or 'Logout' depending on user state.

Note that my Angular knowledge especially around events is not very good, so please feel free to give me advise on best practices.

Here's my current code.

```
app.service('AuthenticationService', function ($rootScope) {

var _loggedIn = "false";

this.login = function (email, password) {

    if (!email || !password) return 1;
    else {
        _loggedIn = "true";
        // broadcast on root scope, so anyone can listen
        $rootScope.$broadcast("loginChanged", 1);
        return 0;
    }
};

this.logout = function (email, password) {
    _loggedIn = "false";
    // broadcast on root scope, so anyone can listen        
    $rootScope.$broadcast("loginChanged", 0);

} 
/*other functions ommited*/
});
```

And in my controller

```
var addListener = function () {
    listener = $scope.$on("loginChanged", function (e, loggedIn) {
        $scope.loginButton.text = loggedIn ? "Log Out" : "Log In";
        $scope.loginButton.link =  loggedIn ? "#/logout" : "#/login";

        console.log("loginChanged: " + loggedIn);
    }); // $on returns a registration function for the listener
};
```

Issue is that `console.log(...)` works fine, though the $scope update is not reflected in UI. I tried wrapping it in `$scope.$apply` which caused in an error saying apply is already in progress.

How do I update the UI from an event ? is there a better/more standard way to achieve the same ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: provide demo that replicates problem. Sounds like might have some nesting that may be causing a scope inheritance problem. Hard to help without markup. If log is working...problem is elsewhere

Comment: Show how are you integrating the `loginButton` variable within HTML

Comment: login button is in HTML as this
`<a href="{{loginButton.link}}">{{loginButton.text}}</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code just works fine. Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/BUOAUgOe1y3e6S2Dq6dW?p=preview

But I wouldn't use $brodcast to notify ui changes. It's like poluting your global namespace with global variables. I would recommend passing in a Service and listen for changes on that service. I've created a plunker to show you what I mean:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MCWThc1ZtaAxmZSTirT6?p=preview

Comment: confusing `_loggedIn` with data argument `loggedIn` used in `$broadcast` which appears to be numeric

Comment: You are right. Confused myself there by refactoring the source code to not use $broadcast and thinking back what the error was it didn't work. Will update my answer. Ty

Comment: less overhead using $broadcast than $watch

Comment: What do you mean with less overhead?

Comment: `$brodcast` is a rare event so uses little processing, `$watch` requires  processor time every time scope changes

Comment: My bad.. while I was messing with this last night, I forgot to call `addListener()` . This works.. Thanks..... Is `$watch` the recommended way to provide events from services/factories .etc. ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Check this post http://eburley.github.io/2013/01/31/angularjs-watch-pub-sub-best-practices.html  charlietfl is right that $watch is more expensive than $broadcast. But as long as its a simple primitive your watching, I wouldn't worry too much about performance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616520/what-is-cheaper-performance-wise-broadcast-or-watch