# AngularJS Events vs Watches

Tags: angularjs

What happens inside AngularJS when a event is fired with the Angular internal event system?

From a performance point of view, should I tend to use watches or events to update parts in my application?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616520/what-is-cheaper-performance-wise-broadcast-or-watch

Answer (score 3):

When a JS event is fired, it is typically handled in the same way that all JS events are handled - there is nothing special or unique about this.

However, angular will wrap the handler inside of an $apply block so that after it executes the function, it can trigger a digest cycle:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
     $element.on('click',function(e){
          ...
      });
 })
```

A digest cycle iterates over all your scope variables, compares each one with the previous value to determine if anything has changed, and if it has, then their corresponding $watch handlers are called to update the view.

Since you are using angular, set up $watch expressions when you want to detect that a model on your scope has changed, and then do any DOM manipulations from inside your $watch handler. If you are concerned about performance, make sure your $watch function is optimized (i.e. avoid full jquery, avoid expensive query selectors, minimize DOM manipulation etc.)

To answer your question, you should use $watches to monitor changes to your models, and $watch functions to update your view.