# Alternatives to angularjs $watch to trigger ui change from service

Tags: angularjs, service

I'm wondering whether there is a different approach to using $watch in order to achieve the following.

Setup:
ControllerA depends on ServiceA.
ControllerB depends on ServiceB.
Current browser view is showing both controllers.

Scenario:
ControllerA is initiating a function on ServiceA, which in turn changes the value of propery X in ServiceB which should be reflected in the UI of ControllerB.

http://jsfiddle.net/zexscvax/2/

html:

```
<div>
    <div ng-controller="ControllerA"></div>
    <div ng-controller="ControllerB">Progress: {{progress}}</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('serviceA', ['$q', '$interval', 'serviceB', function ($q, $interval, serviceB) {

    var service = {};

    service.start = function () {
        var progress = 0;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.promise.then(null,null, notifyServiceB);

        function notifyServiceB() {
          serviceB.update(progress);
        }

        $interval(function() { 
          if (progress == 0.99) {
            deferred.resolve();
          } else {
            progress += 0.01; 
            deferred.notify(progress); 
          }
        }, 50, 100);   
    };

    return service;

}]);

myApp.factory('serviceB', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

    var service = {};

    service.update = function (progress) {
        console.log('update', progress);
        service.progress = progress;
        //$rootScope.$apply(); // <+ ERROR: $digest already in progress
    };

    return service;

}]);

myApp.controller('ControllerA', ['$scope', 'serviceA',
function ($scope, serviceA) {
    serviceA.start();
}]);

myApp.controller('ControllerB', ['$scope', 'serviceB',
function ($scope, serviceB) {
    $scope.progress = serviceB.progress;

    /* this works but I'm not sure whether this is performing

    $scope.$watch(function () { return serviceB.progress; },
        function (value) {
            $scope.progress = serviceB.progress;
        }
    );
    */
}]);
```

Without the $watch in ControllerB for the property X in ServiceB, the UI would not get updated. I've also tried injecting $rootScope in ServiceB in order to run an apply() but that wouldn't work.

I'm not entirely sure whether there's a better way to setup this scenario or whether $watch is fine. I'm a bit worried about performance issues as the value of property X changes almost every 50 ms (it's basically a visual timer counting down).

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Show us some code because $rootScope.$apply() SHOULD work.There is something you're not doing right.You shouldnt have to use $watch in a service.Only in DIRECTIVE and exceptionally in CONTROLLERS.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle. The watch is part of the controller not service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use $watch, you can use $rootScope to broadcast, and on controller B, you can $on this event and handle the view update.

Comment: You're right, that's a valid point. Do you know whether this makes a difference performance wise? As I said the value changes pretty quickly and often so I'm wondering whether broadcasting is the way to go here.

Comment: You can check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616520/what-is-cheaper-performance-wise-broadcast-or-watch