# AngularJS : Watch scope value of a injected service changed in one directive from another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Consider the following scenario.

There are two directives which is independent of each other and I want to share the scope between these two directives. Since they are not nested, I cant use a controller in the directives to share the scope. So I have created a service and injected the service to both of these directives.

So when the value of the service is changed in one directive, I need the same to be updated in the other directive. How can I achieve this? I want this done right, the angular way, with no anti-patterns.

This is what I have tried so far

```
.directive('d1', ['cData', function() {
  return {
    link: function() {
       // this watch is not working
       scope.$watch( function() {
            return cData.Value;
       }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            alert(newValue);
       })
       }
  }
})
.directive('d2', ['cData', function() {
  return {
    link: function() {
      element.on('click', function() {              
        cData.Value = false
        scope.$digest();
      });
      // A watch here is working, I have commented it out
      /*scope.$watch( function() {
            return cd.showStatus;
      }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            alert(newValue)
      })*/
    }
  }
}])
.service('cData', function() {
  this.Value = false;
})
```

I am updating the value of the service in click event of directive `d2` and I need to trigger the watch in the directive `d1`. May be this is not working as the scopes are different for two directives. How can I achieve this, any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Template for directive **d1**

`template : '<div ng-class="{show:cData.Value==true}"></div>'`

To update `{show:cData.Value==true}`

I have to again call scope.$apply() in the event listener of directive `d1`

Hope this is the right approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right path but, I would recommend using `$broadcast` instead of adding a new `$watch`. Adding a new watcher is more of a local scope solution (in my point of view at least). So it all boils down to sharing data between two independent objects. You can achieve this like so:

```
.directive('d1', ['cData', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope) {
       // this watch is not working
       scope.$on('data:changed', function(e, data) {
          alert(data);
       }
       /*
       scope.$watch( function() {
            return cData.Value;
       }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            alert(newValue);
       }) */
       }
  }
})
.directive('d2', ['cData', '$rootScope', function() {
  return {
    link: function() {
      element.on('click', function() { 
        $rootScope.$broadcast('data:changed', { value: false });             
        // cData.Value = false
        // scope.$digest();
      });
      // A watch here is working, I have commented it out
      /*scope.$watch( function() {
            return cd.showStatus;
      }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            alert(newValue)
      })*/
    }
  }
```

}])

From my point of view it's the cleanest way to achieve communication between independent objects/directives without much hassle. And the code is pretty clean and decoupled.

What do you think?

Comment: instead of `data:changed` you can write anything suggestive

Comment: Thanks a lot for this approach and is working. However, I have to call $scope.apply() in the event listener ($on) to update the model.

Comment: Yep that is because element is a jQuery object and is not related to AngularJS.

Comment: @prbaron - which element is jQuery object, $on?

Comment: no, it is 'element'. It represents your directive in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

How is your html for these directives ? can you add attributes ? Because you can watch these attributes.

I am not a fan of event propagation.

Comment: Andrei Cacio's approach is working fine. Should I accept that as the right answer or is there any better approach available. @prbaron

Comment: In that case, could you please suggest me another solution? @prbaron

Comment: Well if we look from a performance point of view, `events` are cheaper than `$watchers`. Watchers are triggered in the dirty-checking process so the function will be executed on every digest cycle weather it's needed or not. Events are triggered only on demand. Here's a good stackoverflow asnwer on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616520/what-is-cheaper-performance-wise-broadcast-or-watch